# jqGrid and Firefox autocomplete conflict

Tags: ajax, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid constructed as it follows in the code below:

```
function radio(value, options, rowObject){
    var radio = '<input type="radio" value=' + value + ' name="radioid" />';
    return radio;
}

function reloadOnEnter(){
    jQuery(':input[name=field1]').keyup(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            var fieldValue = jQuery(':input[name=field1]').attr('value');
            jQuery(':input[name=field1]').attr('value', fieldValue);
            jQuery("#listTable").jqGrid().trigger("reloadGrid");
        }
    });
}

    jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#listTable").jqGrid({
    url: '$content.getURI("myURI")' + '?userId=$userId&pageNo=0&locale=' + '$locale',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames:['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5'],
    colModel :[
        {name:'name', index:'field', width:'8%', search:false, align:'center', formatter: radio, editable:false, sortable: false, resizable:false},
        {name:'name1', index:'field1', width:'23%', sortable: false, resizable:false},
        {name:'name2', index:'field2', width:'23%', sortable: false, resizable:false},
        {name:'name3', index:'field3', width:'23%', sortable: false, resizable:false},
        {name:'name4', index:'field4', width:'23%', sortable: false, resizable:false}
        ],
    width:'768',
    height: 500,
    pager: '#pagerDiv',
    gridview: true,
    rowNum: $rowNr,
    rowTotal: 500,
    sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: true,
    loadComplete: loadCompleteHandler,
    ignoreCase: true
    });
});

jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#listTable").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{
                        stringResult: true,
                        searchOnEnter: false });
});
```

I start typing 'he' and the autocomplete window shows me 'hello' (because I previously typed hello). I select 'hello' and hit enter, and still 'he' is submitted in the ajax request.

My `reloadOnEnter` function is called by the loadCompleteHandler. The interesting thing is that when I query the search field (field1) value is the selected value, but only the typed value is being sent in the request. I would like to send the selected value. How can i achieve this?

**EDIT**:
The `loadCompleteHandler` looks like this:

```
function loadCompleteHandler(){
    reloadOnEnter();
    jQuery("#listTable").jqGrid('setGridHeight', Math.min(500,parseInt(jQuery(".ui-jqgrid-btable").css('height'))));
}
```

(I use Apache Velocity as a template engine! That is why I have variables like `$variable` in the javascript code!)

Comment: You wrote about autocomplete. Where in the code you bind `field1` to jQuery UI autocomplete?

Comment: @Oleg: I might have mistaken the correct word, when I said autocomplete I was referring to the Firefox feature which shows you the list of previously entered values for the field when you click on it (what is the name for this?!?). I am not using jQuery autocomplete function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your main question: you should use [jQuery.val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function instead of `jQuery.attr('value')`.

Many other things in your code seams me strange or unclear. It is not clear for me how you use `reloadOnEnter` in the `loadCompleteHandler`. If would be good if you include the corresponding code fragment. The value for the `url` seems me also very strange. You use additionally `searchOnEnter: false` option of `filterToolbar` but in the `reloadOnEnter` you wait for the 'Enter' key. Inside of the body of `if(e.keyCode == 13)` you get `jQuery(':input[name=field1]').attr('value')` and then set the same value back. Why?

Probably you could describe in the text of your question a little more what you want to archive with the code?

Comment: I have updated the question with source code, so you can see the loadCompleteHandler method. The value of the URL is strange because I use the Velocity engine to parse it, therefore I use special variables like the 'content' variable. I did not set the searchOnEnter because I want it to refresh the grid without 'Enter' and also when 'Enter' is pressed.

Comment: what is the difference between jQuery.val and jQuery.attr?

Comment: @Atticus: You described your main problem as following: "I start typing 'he' and the autocomplete window shows me 'hello' (because I previously typed hello). I select 'hello' and hit enter, and still 'he' is submitted in the ajax request." The code which you posted has no autocomplete, so the main part not posted and one can not use the code to reproduce your problem and to help you. You should post more full code. Moreover your current code have another important bug it makes binding to `keyup` **not once**. On every key press the function are called **multiple times**.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this bug. As I see this happens because thhe grid is reloaded after the reload the binding takes place again. I will have to fix this. Regarding the autocomplete, I have mistaken the right word because I did not refer to jQuery autocomplete, but to the Firefox feature which shows you the list of previously entered values for the field when you click on it. (what is the name for this?!?) There is no more code to post. The problem is cause by this Firefox feature which I called (incorrectly) autocomplete.